# Dell Vostro 3300 Wi-Fi LED not working

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dell, broadcom

I have a Dell Vostro 3300 which I use as a dual-boot.
All the LEDs work perfectly fine on Windows 7 but the Wi-Fi LED does not work on Ubuntu 11.10. There is a Bluetooth LED which works perfectly fine.

I tried installing the proprietary Broadcom wireless driver, it did not help either.

```
Vostro-3300:~$ lspci -vnn | grep 14e4 12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

and the second output is :

```
lsmod | grep brcmsmac 
brcmsmac 631693 0 brcmutil 17837 1 brcmsmac mac80211 310872 1 brcmsmac cfg80211 199587 2 brcmsmac,mac80211 crc_ccitt 12667 1 brcmsmac
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lspci -vnn | grep 14e4` and `lsmod | grep brcmsmac` ?

Comment: `Vostro-3300:~$ lspci -vnn | grep 14e4
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`
and the second output is : `lsmod | grep brcmsmac
brcmsmac              631693  0 
brcmutil               17837  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              310872  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              199587  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
crc_ccitt              12667  1 brcmsmac
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Its in the todo list but not yet supported for the driver you are using.](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211)

`BCM 4313` card uses the opensource broadcom driver called `brcmsmac` and not the proprietary driver `wl`. If you want to light-up the Led you need to blacklist `brcmsmac` and in some cases `bcma` as well and use proprietary driver. So what you may need is:

**Temporarily**

```
sudo rmmod brcmsmac
sudo rmmod bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

**Permanently**

In `/etc/modprobe/blacklist-b43.conf` add `blacklist brcmsmac` `blacklist brcmfmac` `blacklist bcma`

I had to remove `bcma` module as well but it may not be the case with every card. But I had performance issues with  the `wl` driver especially with powersave mode so I avoided installing it and use the kernel provided driver.

Comment: thank you so much! i am using it now. let  me see how well the new driver fares. if it isnt that good, will revert back to good old opensource :). thanks again