# Broadcom 4313 Signal strength very low on an HP Pavilion dv4

Tags: 11.10, broadcom

I have a HP pavilion dv4 4141US laptop running fresh ubuntu 11.10. This laptop has a broadcom 4313gn chipset for the network card. The network card is using the brcmsmac driver. Which, I heard else where on askUbuntu that its the best driver to be using for this card.

I can connect to my network, however I have extremely low network signal. Right now I am right in front of the router, and I only get 72%. If i go to the room directly behind the router's wall, i get no signal, where as with windows 7 I get a nice 70% percent.

**UPDATE**: I use WEP at home and an open wireless connection at work. Both have same result. Both are completely different routers. Also you G

What can i do?

Comment: I didnt find it necessary to blacklist, since my card has loaded the brcmsmac driver. As it says in network information. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the other recommended driver `wl` some people say it works best for them than `brcmsmac` http://askubuntu.com/questions/75398/dell-vostro-3300-wi-fi-led-not-working/75968#75968

Comment: I have really wanted to try this driver, but i never seem able to load it completely. After I run the rmmod commands and the modprobe, I just see the "wireless networks" area disappear from the network manager in the top bar. I also go into settings and activate the proprietary driver, but still, no wireless network options in the network manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bug Reporting

According to [this there is a report](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-August/msg00193.html) of the similar kernel version as used by oneiric having the same issue...

It is probably worth experimenting with different kernels to see if this resolves your issue - see the possible solutions below.

You should file a [kernel launchpad bug report](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) so that the Canonical Kernel maintainers are aware of the issue - possibly they may backport a patch from the latest release candidate in a future kernel build.

When filing the bug-report, they will ask you to test the latest mainline kernel.  To do this, following the instructions below.

## to install a kernel

Navigate to [this website](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v3.1.4-oneiric/) and download the files that look like the following:

`headers_amd64.deb, headers_all.deb & image_amd64.deb` if using 64bit Ubuntu

`headers_i386.deb, headers_all.deb & image_i386.deb` if using 32bit Ubuntu

Install the packages downloaded using the terminal command:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

When booting press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to display your GRUB - this screen lists your kernels - you can boot with any kernel listed including "older linux" option for old kernels.

---

## Possible Solutions

1. Look at the kernel mainline and choose a newer kernel - preferably one that has the *oneiric* name associated with it - however you could also try the very latest (but probably unstable) 2.6.32 release candidates.
2. Looking closely at that bug-report, early in the thread the OP reported that his issue was due to a hidden SSID.  Possibly you can check in your router settings whether you are using a visible SSID or a hidden SSID.
3. Also, the OP reported that he didn't have his particular issue with the older 2.6.39.2 kernel.  You could also try that by downloading this from the [launchpad mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.39.2-oneiric/) and installing this using the instructions above.  Remember to booting into the older kernel by selecting it from GRUB.

### Tidying up

If this doesn't workout for you - remove this kernel using my answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81900/how-do-i-remove-kernel-3-1-that-i-added-via-a-ppa)

If the newer/older kernel works for you then you can use [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990) to "fix" the kernel i.e. to always boot into the newer/older kernel.

---

### Conclusion

As we have discussed - trying all of the above, booting with the older 2.6.39.2 kernel seems to provide you with the best solution.

Comment: Ok I just finished installing, but I see no difference. I think I will take your advice and file a bug report.

Comment: That report you linked to seems exactly my issue. I am having problems following it though, due to the format of the site hahaha. Do you see it concluding in anyway?

Comment: No I am talking about the link you shared: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-August/msg00193.html  They seem to be discussing my exact problem but I cannot understand what they ended up deciding what the problem was or if there is a fix. thanks

Comment: It seems that I am not using this new kernel after I reboot. Uname reports the same version 3.1,4-030104

Comment: Ahh! i missed the "older linux" option in grub. It seems to be much better now :) Is it safe to just set the default grub start up to the older kernel? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: yep - you can set the GRUB_DEFAULT to be the older kernel - see my answer here - it applies to both windows and ubuntu (http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990)  I'll tidy up the answer to reflect what we have been trying - and I'll be deleting the my comments to tidy up the thread.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but could you be able to tell me how to enable pae on 2.6.39 kernel? When I try to do as here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE It says that it is already installed. IF you want, I can open another question.

Comment: that's another question - however saying that, I believe this kernel should automatically default to PAE so you shouldnt need to do anything extra.  If you are finding that you have more than 4GB RAM but `free` is showing less than 4GB then create another question - I'm sure someone more knowledgeable in this particular area will help you out.