# wireless low sensitivity hp pavilion dm1 on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: wireless, hp

I have a recently bought hp pavilion dm1 with Ubuntu 11.10 installed. It is able to detect my personal wireless network when in close proximity to the router, however it fails to do so when I'm in a different room (unless I connected previously), let alone at my university. Any thoughts?

output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 60:d8:19:74:73:6b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.0.0-13-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.50.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 10:1f:74:b7:42:d7
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0104000-f0104fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

output of `iwconfig wlan0`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"my_wireless"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:16:0A:0F:8A:46   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:10  Invalid misc:82   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcom 4313 Signal strength very low on an HP Pavilion dv4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83262/broadcom-4313-signal-strength-very-low-on-an-hp-pavilion-dv4)

Comment: the solution in that linked question was to install the older 2.6.39 kernel...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with the same card *BCM4313*. You don't use the proper driver (*brcmsmac*), the proper driver is *wl*.

Install the [proprietary one](http://tuxcanfly.appspot.com/tag/ubuntu-broadcom-4313-43xx-bcmwl) from Broadcom.

Then blacklist in */etc/modprob.d/blacklist.conf*

```
blacklist bcm43xx  
blacklist brcmsmac  
blacklist bcma   
blacklist b43    
blacklist ssb
```

Restart and check that:

```
lspci -k | grep  wl
```

Hope it works for you like for me (very strong signal).

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Thank you for this great answer! If you have a question yourself, then please use the [Ask question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button to ask a new one. Don't ask it in side of an answer. Hope you enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 0):

add contrib and non-free to your source.list

/etc/apt/sources.list

> deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

run the following command as root:

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
>
> modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
>
> modprobe wl

and configure you wifi