# Broadcom 4313 (gn) wirelless card on HP Pavilion g6 weak signal but close to AP

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom 4313 Signal strength very low on an HP Pavilion dv4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83262/broadcom-4313-signal-strength-very-low-on-an-hp-pavilion-dv4)

I installed fresh Ubuntu 11.04 and i have wireless connection but i have to be very close to the router to have signal. I looked everywhere i can't manage to find a solution.
In my grub it says that i have : 
**3.1.4-030104 generic

old ones : 

3.0.0-14 generic

3.0.0-12 generic**
kernels.

I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83262/broadcom-4313-signal-strength-very-low-on-an-hp-pavilion-dv4) but i think this is for older versions of Ubuntu.
On Windows 7 the wireless card is working flawlessly. Please help me to find a solution I'll be grateful.

Comment: no it is not ... I didn't find the solution in that post ;)

Comment: you need the 2.6.39.2 kernel - have you tried that?

Comment: Currently downloading... I hope it will work... thank you for your fast answer

Comment: It is not working! I load up this kernel and when i try to connect to a wireless connection i realize that there is no option for that in the notification panel. I tried switching the wireless switch but It ain't working...